# Better way to bulkify trigger

Tags: bulkification

The trigger below works but I would like to know what I can do to avoid the query in the for loop.

```
trigger eOneAutoCreateProductResponse on Product_Configuration__c (after insert) {

    if(checkRecursive.runOnce()) {

        /**variables**/
        Integer cnt;
        Id acctid;


        for (Product_Configuration__c car: trigger.new) {
            if(car.RecordTypeId=='012550000008U4m' ||
                car.RecordTypeId=='012550000008U4p' ||
                car.RecordTypeId=='012550000008U4n' ||
                car.RecordTypeId=='012550000008U4r' ||
                car.RecordTypeId=='012550000008U4q') {
                Product_Configuration__c pc = [
                    SELECT Id, PGPOption__c, Account__c
                    FROM Product_Configuration__c
                    WHERE Account__c = :car.Account__c
                    AND RecordTypeId = '012550000008U4d'
                ];
                System.debug (logginglevel.DEBUG, 'Step 1');
                Product_Response__c rec= new Product_Response__c();  

                rec.RecordTypeid = '012550000008U53';
                rec.Format_Type__c ='277CA';
                rec.Mailbox_Folder_Name__c ='reports';
                rec.CompressedOption__c ='None';
                rec.ProductConfigurationID__c = car.Id;

                if(car.Report_Type__c == 'NORPT - No Report') { 
                    rec.Status_Description__c ='C - Cancelled';
                }
                else {
                    rec.Status_Description__C = car.Status_Description__c;
                }

                if(pc.PGPOption__c != Null) {
                    rec.PGPOption__c = pc.PGPOption__c;
                }
                else {
                    rec.pgpoption__c = 'None';
                }
                Insert rec;
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete...

Comment: tip -- don't use hard-coded recordTypeIds -- instead, for code readability, query for the recordTypeIds from `RecordType` using the record type's `developerName` - and use a custom setting to define which recordtypes you care about.  If the recordtype is constructed first in the sandbox and then migrated to production, the ids won't be the same

Answer (score 1):

1. Loop through the trigger.new list of Product_Configuration__c and
   collect all the Account Ids that fit your criteria in a set.
2. Use that set in the WHERE clause of your one SOQL query.
3. Convert the list to a Map.
4. Use the map as a lookup table when you need to get PGPOption__c as you loop through the trigger.new list again.

Code:

```
trigger eOneAutoCreateProductResponse on Product_Configuration__c (after insert) {  if(checkRecursive.runOnce()) {
    /**variables**/
    Integer cnt;
    Id acctid;
    /** create a set of Account Ids **/
    set<Id> acctIdList = new set<Id>();          
    for (Product_Configuration__c car: trigger.new) {
        if(car.RecordTypeId=='012550000008U4m' ||
            car.RecordTypeId=='012550000008U4p' ||
            car.RecordTypeId=='012550000008U4n' ||
            car.RecordTypeId=='012550000008U4r' ||
            car.RecordTypeId=='012550000008U4q') {
            /** if it meets criteria, add to the set **/
            acctIdList.add(car.Account__c);     
        }
    }

    /* execute one SOQL Query outside for loop */
    Product_Configuration__c pc = [
                SELECT Id, PGPOption__c, Account__c
                FROM Product_Configuration__c
                WHERE Account__c IN :acctIdList
                AND RecordTypeId = '012550000008U4d'];

    /** convert list to map **/
    map<Id, Product_Configuration__c> acctMap = 
        new map<Id, Product_Configuration__c>(pc);

    for (Product_Configuration__c car: trigger.new) {

        System.debug (logginglevel.DEBUG, 'Step 1');
        Product_Response__c rec= new Product_Response__c();  

        rec.RecordTypeid = '012550000008U53';
        rec.Format_Type__c ='277CA';
        rec.Mailbox_Folder_Name__c ='reports';
        rec.CompressedOption__c ='None';
        rec.ProductConfigurationID__c = car.Id;

        if(car.Report_Type__c == 'NORPT - No Report') { 
            rec.Status_Description__c ='C - Cancelled';
        }
        else {
            rec.Status_Description__C = car.Status_Description__c;
        }

        /** use map to lookup PGPOption twice!! **/
        if(acctMap.get(car.Id).PGPOption__c != Null) {
            rec.PGPOption__c = acctMap.get(car.Id).PGPOption__c;
        }
        else {
            rec.pgpoption__c = 'None';
        }
        Insert rec;
```

Comment: Sorry but not sure I am understanding.  Could you please give me the code for that?